# Display error and exit when cd exits with error

Tags: bash

I want to let my script exit with a message when a cd command fails. I tried that by do the following:

```
cd $foo || echo "Error xyz"; exit 1
```

However, exit gets called regardless of the cd's success. When I type the following, it does not work either, because exit only exits the subshell:

```
cd $foo || ( echo "Error xyz"; exit 1 )
```

How can I achieve the desired behaviour without defining a function? Of course I could just compare $(pwd) with $foo, but that could lead to problems regarding symlinks and stuff.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [`{ list; }` compound command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping). The list of commands is executed in the current shell context:

```
cd "$foo" || { echo "Error xyz"; exit 1; }
```

(Note the trailing semicolon or newline is required.)

---

The most common definition of functions in `bash` usually uses exactly this  compound command for the "function body":

```
f() { list; }
```

although, `bash` functions can be defined with *any compound command* for their body, for example:

```
f() ( list; )
f() (( $1 > 10 ))
f() [[ $1 != "test" ]]
```

even:

```
f() for i in {1..10}; do echo $i; done
f() case ... esac
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just use an if statement. It is more readable in most cases, especially if you want to craft a proper error message:

```
if ! cd "${dir}" ; then
    echo "Failed to enter folder ${dir}"
    echo "Aborting"
    exit 1
fi
```