# bash - Exiting current function by calling another function?

Tags: bash, shell

Is it possible to have a function (or something similar) in bash that when called, will return *from its calling function*?

Let me explain... In my shell scripts I have some some common functions that I can use everywhere

```
function die () { echo "$0: ERROR : ${2:-} $(date)"; <script-specific cleanup>; exit $1; }
# Example use
[ $count -lt 5 ] && die 1 "Incorrect usage count='$count' must be >5."
```

Which is great if you want to exit your script entirely. But can you "Do some common cleanup tasks and exit the current function" in a function (or something similar)? Obviously, the `return` in the function below will simply return from `die_fn` and not from its caller.

```
# This of course is no good
function die_fn () { echo "$0: ERROR : ${2:-} $(date)"; <cleanup>; return $1; }
function foo ()
{
    ...
    [ $found -eq 0 ] && die_fn 1 'No targets founds. Skipping build'
    ...
}
```

You could, I suppose, put `echo "$0: ERROR : ${2:-} $(date)"; <script-specific cleanup>; return $1;` in `die_fn.sh` and *source* it when needed, but that is a lot of work for what is supposed to be a simplification.

**Update**
It seems very likely that this is not possible in any elegant and maintainable way. Barring any new revelations, I suspect I will just append `&& return 1` to the line when I want brevity, and have a full `if` statement when that's not desired.

Comment: No; that's why more modern languages have exceptions, which are effectively interceptable calls to `exit`.

Comment: I would simply call my cleanup function and append `&& return;` when necessary.

Comment: If you do  `&& { die_fn 1 "..."; return 1; }` everybody can clearly see that there is an exit to the function.  For cleanup you may consider `trap cleanup EXIT`

Comment: @ULick, I believe after testing that if I do that, then it will simply die and the whole script will terminate, rather than simply `return`ing from the function.

Comment: I assumed the function die_fn without the `exit` in it (should have choosen another name for it). And it shows the exit/return from the function `foo()`. In general I don't like it, if a function doesn't come back to where it left.

Answer (score 1):

The closest approximation of such behavior (that I can think of), would be to define the parent [function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions) (`foo`) as a [**subshell** compound command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping) (if that's acceptable for your use case), and then simply use `exit` in `die` function to exit the innermost shell (i.e. the parent `foo` function).

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

die() { echo "$0: DIE: ${2:-} $(date)"; exit "$1"; }

foo() (
    echo "In foo"
    die 1 'No targets found. Skipping build'
)

foo
echo "foo exited with $?"
```

The result:

```
In foo
./script.sh: DIE: No targets found. Skipping build Sun 19 Nov 21:18:42 CET 2017
foo exited with 1
```

Comment: Thanks @randomir. I didn't know I could write a function as a subshell compound command. That would definitely work for my situation, but I worry it is too clever for its own good and somebody (possibly even myself years later after forgetting) would break it and not even realize.

Comment: You shouldn't worry, there's nothing special about subshell function. In fact, *any* compound command can form a function body. For a few examples (even extremes like `case`/`for`/`while`) check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47033460/404556).